# Как получить  информацию с двух одинаковых тегов?

Tags: preg_match, php, парсер, html

Создаю парсер для одного сайта, не могу извлечь данные со 2-го тега

```
preg_match("/<td><div class=\"g ([A-Za-z]+)\" title=\"([А-Яа-я]+)\"><\/div><\/td><td>(<div class=\"g ([A-Za-z]+)\" title=\"([А-Яа-я]+)\"><\/div>|-)<\/td>/i",$info,$type);
print_r($type);
```

Этот код не работает, не могу понят почему.

Comment: [Ознакомьтесь со статьей на stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Ещё есть варианты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_match_all()`

> `preg_match_all` - Выполняет глобальный
> поиск шаблона в строке Описание `int
> preg_match_all ( string pattern,
> string subject, array &matches [, int
> flags [, int offset]] )`
>
> Ищет в строке `subject` все совпадения
> с шаблоном pattern и помещает
> результат в массив matches в порядке,
> определяемом комбинацией флагов `flags`.
>
> **После нахождения первого соответствия
> последующие поиски будут
> осуществляться не с начала строки, а
> от конца последнего найденного
> вхождения**.